# Apache signature on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, vps

Hey guys, I'm trying to remove any infos relative to apache, so I added to my httpd.conf in /etc/apache2 these two lines:

```
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

then I restart the server, but infos still show up. So I decided to edit directly apache2.conf at the whole bottom, and added these two lines again, and it worked :o

Do you have an idea of what would cause this? Something in apach2.conf overwriting my rules after it includes the httpd.conf?

thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the default `apache2.conf` includes everything inside of `/etc/apache2/conf.d`.  If you look inside `/etc/apache2/conf.d/security`, you're likely to see the following:

```
#ServerSignature Off
ServerSignature On
```

Because of the order that files are included (I believe its alphabetically by globbing), this means that the values in `security` are overriding the ones in `httpd.conf`.  Simply make the change in `security`, or comment it out and put it in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! it's just weird that if httpd.conf should be the user's config, it should also be included at the end :o, weird...

Comment: Well, the idea is that you should never be editing `apache2.conf` directly.  Its the same with init scripts... for example, you should NEVER be editing `/etc/init.d/apache2` directly, you should be editing `/etc/sysconfig/apache2`, which would then be sourced by the init file.

Comment: ok, but it's safe to edit anything in /etc/apache2/conf.d ?

Comment: Sure, or at least--you'll just be adding onto the existing `apache2.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a line `ServerSignature On` in any of the included conf files coming after the line `include httpd.conf` in `apache2.conf`, which overwrites your statements.

Answer (score 0):

look in

```
/etc/apache2/conf.d/security
```